# Call Activity method from adapter

Tags: android, list, adapter, addressing

Is it possible to call method that is defined in `Activity` from `ListAdapter`?

(I want to make a `Button` in `list's` row and when this button is clicked, it should perform the method, that is defined in corresponding Activity. I tried to set `onClickListener` in my `ListAdapter` but I don't know how to call this method, what's its path...)

when I used `Activity.this.method()` I get the following error:

```
No enclosing instance of the type Activity is accessible in scope
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: you cannot call activity.this in some other class unless it is a inner class to that activity. follow @Eldhose M Babu solution for your case

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Yes you can.

In the adapter Add a new Field :

```
private Context mContext;
```

In the adapter Constructor add the following code :

```
public AdapterName(......, Context context) {
  //your code.
  this.mContext = context;
}
```

In the getView(...) of Adapter:

```
Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(yourButtonId);
btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mContext instanceof YourActivityName) {
      ((YourActivityName)mContext).yourDesiredMethod();
    }
  }
});
```

replace with your own class names where you see your code, your activity etc.

If you need  to use this same adapter for more than  one activity then :

Create an Interface

```
public interface IMethodCaller {
    void yourDesiredMethod();
}
```

Implement this interface in activities you require to have this method calling functionality.

Then in Adapter getView(), call like:

```
Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(yourButtonId);
btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mContext instanceof IMethodCaller) {
            ((IMethodCaller) mContext).yourDesiredMethod();
        }
    }
});
```

You are done. If you need to use this adapter for activities which does not require this calling mechanism, the code will not execute (If check fails).

Comment: I have similar problem. in my case, it is Fragment what should i use instead of `((YourActivityName)mContext).yourDesiredMethod();`

Comment: As this is a popular question, I would strongly suggest NOT TO USE this solution. You should avoid class casting here, because this might lead to runtime exceptions.

Comment: Eldhose bro, I have nothing against you but answer below is best practice. You can even read in comments. You should not cast mContext to your Activity as you are avoiding reuse of code. Now this adapter can only be used inside the Activity which you have casted your mContext variable to, where if you have a listener defined then you can reuse the same Adapter in another Activity. Trust me i have spent enough time in industry and I am just trying to help you here, please don't take it personally.

Comment: This solution is one of the best I've ever found on SO. So thanks a lot Mr. Babu. Calling the Activity's methods by this, gives the whole app a 500% kicking performance boost -> I don't need to reload the database in the adapter, which I need to access. I don't care about "years in industry", I'm looking for stable and working solutions and I'm quite sure, I will not find a better way to get access. Maybe I could set up the DB as a singleton, but this is not the way I want to "un-structure" my project.

Comment: if in am using same adapter in one or more activity then ?

Comment: @RAM if you need to call the same method in more than one activity, you need to create an interface with that method name. Then implement that interface in what all activities you need the method call to be availed. Then  in the click listener, check instance of your interface rather than using activity name.

Comment: You can't believe How Thankful I am to your for this Answer
You are Amazing Had the other problem but though this I solved mine (Y)

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to <<myactivityname>>

Comment: This solution is an anti-pattern, you should't tightly couple an adapter with activity.

Answer (score 141):

You can do it this way:

Declare interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public void foo();
}
```

Let your Activity imlement it:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface{
        public void foo(){
            //do stuff
        }
        
        public onCreate(){
            //your code
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this); //this will work as your 
                                                     //MyInterface listener
        }
    }
```

Then pass your activity to ListAdater:

```
public MyAdapter extends BaseAdater{
    private MyInterface listener;

    public MyAdapter(MyInterface listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

And somewhere in adapter, when you need to call that Activity method:

```
listener.foo();
```

Comment: I first thought of the method above as you would with fragments but this is the best solution!

Comment: wich is my InterfaceListener? how can initialize it ?
public MyAdapter(MyInterface listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

Comment: How do you pass the interface to the adapter though (from the Activity)

Comment: @Brandon you can pass it is constructor parameter in adapter.

Comment: @Brandon , just add 'this' to pass interface to adapter 
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);

Comment: NullPointerException in my Adapter extends RealmBaseAdapter

Answer (score 78):

## Original:

I understand the current answer but needed a more clear example. Here is an example of what I used with an `Adapter`(RecyclerView.Adapter) and an `Activity`.

### In your Activity:

This will implement the `interface` that we have in our `Adapter`. In this example, it will be called when the user clicks on an item in the `RecyclerView`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterCallback {

    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onMethodCallback() {
       // do something
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    }
}
```

### In your Adapter:

In the `Activity`, we initiated our `Adapter` and passed this as an argument to the constructer. This will initiate our `interface` for our callback method. You can see that we use our callback method for user clicks.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private AdapterCallback adapterCallback;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        try {
            adapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // simple example, call interface here
        // not complete
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    adapterCallback.onMethodCallback();
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                   // do something
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static interface AdapterCallback {
        void onMethodCallback();
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me! imo, most complete working code so far!

Comment: Thanks for this solution

Comment: this answer should have more upvotes, it´s a clean and perfect solution.

Comment: Hi @Jared - Can you right the same sample with `EventBus` as you suggested?

Comment: @Tohid Actually, I rather use callbacks to make unit testing easier. If you want to try eventbus, look at my similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27716730/950427.

Comment: Hello @JaredBurrows. I tried to implement what you have posted, but I am facing some errors. If you have time could you please check the question I've posted?  It will be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, this is right solution.

Answer (score 18):

**Basic and simple.**

In your adapter simply use this.

`((YourParentClass) context).functionToRun();`

Comment: not a good practice because you are restricting your class to work only with 
YourParentClass type instead of any class, but works if you dont care about reusing it, if you also rename a class the code breaks...

Comment: ((YourParentClass) parent.getContext()).functionToRun(); also works like this

Answer (score 10):

For Kotlin:

In your adapter, simply call

```
(context as Your_Activity_Name).yourMethod()
```

Answer (score 7):

One more way is::

Write a method in your adapter lets say 
public void callBack(){}.

Now while creating an object for adapter in activity override this method.
Override method will be called when you call the method in adapter.

```
Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter() {
  @Override
  public void callBack() {
    // dosomething
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin there is now a cleaner way by using lambda functions, no need for interfaces:

```
class MyAdapter(val adapterOnClick: (Any) -> Unit) {
    fun setItem(item: Any) {
        myButton.setOnClickListener { adapterOnClick(item) }
    }
}

class MyActivity {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var myAdapter = MyAdapter { item -> doOnClick(item) }
    }


    fun doOnClick(item: Any) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin you could do something like :

`if(context is MainActivity){ context.functionToCall(values) }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (parent.getContext() instanceof yourActivity) {
  //execute code
}
```

this condition will enable you to execute something if the Activity which has the `GroupView` that requesting views from the `getView()` method of your `adapter` is `yourActivity`

NOTE : `parent` is that GroupView

Comment: this GroupView requests views from the adapter when it calls the `getView()` method.....so we get the context of that GroupView, and examine it through the condition above

Comment: BTW it is not `GroupView` it is `ViewGroup`