# How to call a method defined in a ListFragment from an adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

I've got a `ListFragment` and a custom adapter.

From the adapter I get the `onClick` event from a button defined in the rows. In the `onClick` method I get some id, which I'd like to pass to the `ListFragment` to do some stuff.

How can I call the method showTask in the `ListFragment` from the adapter?

**listfragment**

```
public class TaskListFragment extends ListFragment{

    /* ... */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new TaskListAdapter(getActivity(), data);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }   

    public void showTask(long id) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        TaskFragment taskFragment = new TaskFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong("id", id);
        taskFragment.setArguments(args);

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, taskFragment);
        ft.commit();         
    }
}
```

**adapter**

```
public class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task>{

    /* ... */

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long id = (Integer) v.getTag();
            // how can I call showTask(id) ?
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Why is your onClick method in the adapter and not in the activity?

Comment: Let your fragment implement `IShowTask` interface (which has `showTask` method) then let adapter have `setShowTaskListener(IShowTask )` method ... then ... you are the programmer, don't ya? :)

Comment: I've posted an answer the way you want it, but you shouldn't create `OnClickListeners` for every view. You should consider putting an `OnListItemClickListener` on your `ListView`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A common solution is for the adapter to be an inner class of the fragment, so it can just call the method directly.

Or, pass the fragment (or some interface implemented by the fragment) to the adapter via its constructor.

Comment: @CommomsWare You can say I am a bad programmer, but I wouldn't be able to solve a lot of my problems if it weren't for you :)

Answer (score 15):

Create your adapter like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new TaskListAdapter(getActivity(), data, TaskListFragment.this);        
}
```

Which would change your adapter constructor to:

```
public TaskListAdapter(Context context, List<Task> data, TastListFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

And now, you have an object that points to your TaskListFragment:

```
private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long id = (Integer) v.getTag();
        fragment.showTask(id);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I'll use an interface implemented in the Fragment instead.

Comment: For noobs, here is an implementation of interface in second half of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12142492/609782