# How to create interface between Fragment and adapter?

Tags: java, android, interface

I have fragment with `ListView`, say `MyListFragment`, and custom `CursorAdapter`.
I'm setting `onClickListener` in this adapter for the button in the list row.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public interface AdapterInterface {
        public void buttonPressed();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        ...

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // some action
                // need to notify MyListFragment
            }
        });
    }
}

public MyListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterInterface {

    @Override
    public void buttonPressed() {
        // some action
    }
}
```

I need to notify fragment when the button is pressed. How to invoke this interface?

Help, please.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Make a new constructor and an instance variable:

```
AdapterInterface buttonListener;

public MyListAdapter (Context context, Cursor c, int flags, AdapterInterface buttonListener)
{
  super(context,c,flags);
  this.buttonListener = buttonListener;
}
```

When the Adapter is made, the instance variable will be given the proper reference to hold.

To call the Fragment from the click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   buttonListener.buttonPressed();
}
```

When making the `Adapter`, you will have to also pass your Fragment off to the Adapter. For example

```
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter (getActivity(), myCursor, myFlags, this);
```

since `this` will refer to your Fragment, which is now an `AdapterInterface`.

Keep in mind that on orientation of the Fragment changes, it will most likely be recreated. If your Adapter isn't recreated, it can potentially keep a reference to a nonexistent object, causing errors.

Comment: Where do I put the code for the first part? 

    AdapterInterface buttonListener;

I tried sticking it in my adapter but that threw an error.

Thanks

Comment: Awesome!! +1 for **AdapterInterface buttonListener** in constructor. Thank you.

Answer (score 73):

## Using Eventbus:

Examples:

https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/rxbus

or

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

## Using Interfaces:

I understand the current answer but needed a more clear example. Here is an example of what I used with an `Adapter`(RecyclerView.Adapter) and a `Fragment`.

**Create `Callback` Interface:**

```
public interface AdapterCallback {
    void onMethodCallback();
}
```

**Passing in `Callback`/`Fragment`:**

This will implement the `interface` that we have in our `Adapter`. In this example, it will be called when the user clicks on an item in the `RecyclerView`.

**In your `Fragment`:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterCallback {

    private MyAdapter mMyAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onMethodCallback() {
       // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(this); // this class implements callback
    }
}
```

**Use the `Callback` in your Adapter:**

In the `Fragment`, we initiated our `Adapter` and passed this as an argument to the constructer. This will initiate our `interface` for our callback method. You can see that we use our callback method for user clicks.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;

    public MyAdapter(AdapterCallback callback) {
        this.mAdapterCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        // simple example, call interface here
        // not complete
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**or Use the `Fragment` in your Adapter:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;

    public MyAdapter(Fragment fragment) {
        try {
            this.mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) fragment);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Fragment must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        // simple example, call interface here
        // not complete
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback();
                } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
                   // do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the following for FragementActivity.. but I am getting NPE: http://pastebin.com/wc2ByiFz - if i don't use the callback and just log value things are fine.

Comment: @TheDevMan NPE where? I use this method of interfaces in app of my apps.

Comment: Hmm. Whenever I use the callback I get NPE but when I don't call and just have the log it is working.I have detail question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092877/click-event-from-adapter-to-activity-or-fragment-in-android - Can you help fix this? I have been struggling to get this solved.

Comment: Once again, NPE where? The log you showed is not from my example: `at com.ylg.link.CustomAdapter$1.onGroupExpand(CustomAdapter.java:149)`.  Get what solved? I have not really used the ExpandableListView before.

Comment: Hmm where ever I am trying call the callback in OnClickListner. Similar to your answer. You are trying mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback(); in OnClick right.. the place in my code.

Comment: You are getting a NPE because you need to initialize it like I did in the constructor: `this.mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) fragment);`

Comment: I have done that now. Now I am getting the Fragment must implement adapterCallBack Exception

Comment: Yes, please read my example. You must `implements AdapterCallback {` in your Fragment.

Comment: True.. hence I have update my question here please check; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092877/click-event-from-adapter-to-activity-or-fragment-in-android Thanks!

Comment: any idea for the other way around? a interface implementation in the recylcer view holder perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849380/recyclerview-header-access-objects-from-the-header-in-the-activity-fragment

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one... @JaredBurrows Perfect explained now I know how to use interfaces and its uses ;) Thanks.

Comment: @Skizo Thank you! I think it is relaly first come, first serve ha. I am glad my answer helped.

Comment: Even i m getting NPE on my interface object in getview(). I have declared it properly still showing null pointer exception. Can anyone ans this?

Comment: @Azharosws Please read the top of the post. I would highly suggest using EventBus.

Comment: ok i will try to use that ..Thanks for suggestion. But i really want to know why it is giving null pointer error? Although i have declared all the matter properly.

Comment: EventBus needs to die.

Answer (score 38):

Follow the 2 steps below for receive callback from `Adapter` in `Fragment (or Activity)`

**First:** In your `Adapter`

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < RecyclerListAdapter.ItemViewHolder > {
    ...
    private ListAdapterListener mListener;

    public interface ListAdapterListener { // create an interface
        void onClickAtOKButton(int position); // create callback function
    }

    public RecyclerListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList < Items > listItems, ListAdapterListener mListener) { // add the interface to your adapter constructor
        ...
        this.mListener = mListener; // receive mListener from Fragment (or Activity)
    }
    ...
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // use callback function in the place you want
                mListener.onClickAtOKButton(position);
            }
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Second:** In your `Fragment (or Activity)`, there are 2 ways for implement callback method

*Way 1*

```
 public MyListFragment extends Fragment {
     ...
     public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
         ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), listItems, new ListAdapter.ListAdapterListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClickAtOKButton(int position) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click ok button at" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
         ...
     }
 }
```

*Way 2*

```
public MyListFragment extends Fragment implements ListAdapter.ListAdapterListener {
     ...
     public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListAdapter  adapter = new ListAdapter (getActivity(), listItems, this);
        ...   
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickAtOKButton(int position) {  
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click ok button at" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
    }          
}
```

Comment: In way1, with anonymous class implementation if the fragment gets destroyed and the on onClickAtOkButton() is called from some thread. What are the chances of memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the way an activity and a fragment should communicate. In the constructor of your adapter, pass a reference of your fragment, cast it to your interface and just call yourReference.buttonPressed() on your onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

a solution for NPE is first to make conctractor in your Fragment like that

```
public MyFragment MyFragment(){
        return this;
    }
```

then initialize your listener is adapter like that

```
Lisener lisener = new MyFragment();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor like that:

```
  public MyAdapter(Activity activity,AlertMessageBoxOk alertMessageBoxOk) {

  this.mActivity = activity;

  mAlertMessageBoxOk = alertMessageBoxOk;

}
```

call the interface from adapter use any event

```
mAlertMessageBoxOk.onOkClick(5);
```

after that implement AlertMessageBoxOk interface to your fragment like this,

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment implements AlertMessageBoxOk {

@Override
public void onOkClick(int resultCode) {

  if(resultCode==5){

  enter code here 

      }
    } 
 }
```