# How to get switchcompat state in recyclerview rows adapter

Tags: android

My adapter :

```
public class AdsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdsAdapter.AdsViewHolder> {
    private List<Ads> adsList;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public class AdsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtAdTitle, txtCompanyName;
        public NetworkImageView imgCompany;
        public SwitchCompat adState;

        public AdsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtAdTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_ad_title);
            txtCompanyName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_company);
            imgCompany = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_company);
            adState = (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ad_state);

            if (GlobalValues.switchCompat.equals("My Advertisements"))
                adState.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                adState.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public AdsAdapter(List<Ads> adsList) {
        this.adsList = adsList;
    }

    @Override
    public AdsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ads_list_row, parent, false);
        return new AdsViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Ads ads = adsList.get(position);
        holder.txtAdTitle.setText(ads.getAdTitle());
        holder.txtCompanyName.setText(ads.getCompanyName());

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        holder.imgCompany.setImageUrl(ads.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);

        if (GlobalValues.switchCompat.equals("My Advertisements")) {
            holder.adState.setChecked(ads.getAdState());

            holder.adState.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // do something, the isChecked will be
                    // true if the switch is in the On position
                    Log.d("SwitchCompat", String.valueOf(isChecked));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adsList.size();
    }
}
```

Fragment :

```
public class MyAdvertisementFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = MyAdvertisementFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button addNewAd;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private String uid, api_key;

    private List<Ads> adsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdsAdapter mAdapter;

    public MyAdvertisementFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myadvertisements, container, false);

        GlobalValues.switchCompat = "My Advertisements";

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        uid = user.get("uid");
        api_key = user.get("api_key");

        addNewAd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_advertisement);
        addNewAd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Launch main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddNewAdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ads_recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new AdsAdapter(adsList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                String adId = adsList.get(position).getAdId();
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AdDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("adId", adId);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        getUserAdsList();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private MyAdvertisementFragment.ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MyAdvertisementFragment.ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

    private void getUserAdsList() {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_get_user_ads";

        pDialog.setMessage("Lütfen Bekleyin...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                ApiRoutes.URL_ADS+ "/" + uid, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User Ads Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        adsList.clear();
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        JSONArray adsArray = jObj.getJSONArray("ads");
                        Ads ads;
                        for (int i = 0; i < adsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonobject = adsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            boolean ad_state = (jsonobject.getString("ad_state").equals("1")) ? true : false;
                            ads = new Ads(jsonobject.getString("id"), jsonobject.getString("title"), jsonobject.getString("company_name"), ApiRoutes.FOLDER_IMG + "/" + uid + "/profile_img.png", ad_state);
                            adsList.add(ads);
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "User Ads Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("uid", uid);

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Authorization", api_key);

                return headers;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

I have switchcompat for every recyclerviewer' s rows. I add the switchcompat listener in adapter. But how can i handle, which switchcompat changed ? 
Because my recyclerviewer' s touchlistener in fragment. But switchcompat listener in adapter so i could not get position of which row's switchcompat clicked.

Comment: try follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/37535113/5381331. this is a example with `Button` but I think `SwitchCompat` is same

Comment: @PhanVănLinh thank you, it works :)