# Android Studio CallBack from Adapter to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, android-adapter

My goal is to activate the "RefreshList ()" function of the Fragment from the Adapter through the callback.
But Fragment documentation tells me the following message from the photo:
[image]
I supposed that he asked me to send the callback but I do not know how it is done, thank you very much for your help

I attach my fragment code and adapter in case it helps
**AlertasFragment:**

```
public class AlertasFragment extends BaseFragment implements Alerts_Adapter.AdapterCallback {

    private ImageView alertsConfig;

    //Like myAds
    private String userId, TipoAnuncio;
    ArrayList<String> AlertsList;
    ArrayList<String> alertsTypeList;

    com.petrace.petrace.petrace.models.Pet Pet;
    //galeria
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Alerts_Adapter adapter;
    private List<MyAdsCard> myAdsObjectList;
    MyAdsCard a;
    //empty ads
    private TextView noAlerts;
    //progressbar
    private LinearLayout showLoading;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alertas, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        //((MainActivity) getActivity()).updateToolbarTitle("Search");

        alertsConfig = view.findViewById(R.id.alertsConfig);
        alertsConfig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.it_doesnt_work, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Like myAds
        userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        AlertsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //noAlerts
        noAlerts = view.findViewById(R.id.noAlerts);
        //progress bar
        showLoading = view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_progressBar);
        //galeria
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        myAdsObjectList= new ArrayList<MyAdsCard>();
        adapter = new Alerts_Adapter(getActivity(), myAdsObjectList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);//columnas que quieres por filas
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepareAlerts();


        //Log.i("nofares", "onCreateView: entra");
        return view;
    }

    private void prepareAlerts() {

        showLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //coge Id anuncios usuario
        DatabaseReference ref1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference ref2,ref3;
        ref2 = ref1.child("Usuarios").child(userId).child("Alerts");
        ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // Result will be holded Here
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    AlertsList.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey())); //add result into array list
                    //alertsTypeList.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue()));
                }
                if (AlertsList.isEmpty())
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    noAlerts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        //recorre anuncioarray para ver si el anuncio id coincide con alguno

            ref3 = ref1.child("Alertas");//recorre todos los strings tipode anuncios
            ref3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //mira a cada anuncio
                    for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (String id : AlertsList)//compara si algún id de anunci coincideix amb els id de la llista
                        {
                            //idAnuncio = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                            if (String.valueOf(dsp.getKey()).equals(id)) {
                                //info principal que vull agafar
                                String idAd = dsp.getKey();
                                String name = dsp.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                String time = dsp.child("fecha").getValue(String.class);
                                String description = dsp.child("descripción").getValue(String.class);
                                String imageURL = dsp.child("photoUrl").getValue(String.class);
                                String TipoAnuncio = dsp.child("typeAd").getValue(String.class);


                                //converteix string data a long
                                Date date = null;
                                long dateLong = 0;
                                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
                                try {
                                    date = format.parse(time);
                                    dateLong = date.getTime();
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                String DifTime = getTimeDifference(dateLong);
                                //calcula la diferencia tiempo
                                //calcula diferencia tiempo en segundos para ordenarlo en galería
                                DateTime today = DateTime.now();
                                DateTime modified = new DateTime(dateLong, DateTimeZone.UTC);
                                int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(modified, today).getSeconds();

                                //declara objeto
                                a = new MyAdsCard(id,TipoAnuncio, name, description,DifTime, imageURL, seconds);
                                myAdsObjectList.add(a);
                                //ordena de més recent a més antic

                                Collections.sort(myAdsObjectList, new Comparator<MyAdsCard>(){
                                    @Override
                                    public int compare(MyAdsCard o1, MyAdsCard o2) {

                                        int sec1 =0;
                                        int sec2 =0;
                                        try {
                                            sec1= NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(String.valueOf(o1.getTimeSeconds())).intValue();//cambia el valor string en int per comparar
                                            sec2=NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(String.valueOf(o2.getTimeSeconds())).intValue();
                                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        if (sec1 < sec2) return -1;// para ordenarlo
                                        else if (sec1 == sec2) return 0;
                                        else if (sec1 > sec2) return 1;

                                        else return 0;
                                    }
                                });



                            }
                        }

                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        showLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }








    private String getTimeDifference(long date) {
        DateTime today = DateTime.now();
        DateTime modified = new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.UTC);

        int years = Years.yearsBetween(modified, today).getYears();
        int months = Months.monthsBetween(modified, today).getMonths();
        int days = Days.daysBetween(modified, today).getDays();
        int hours = Hours.hoursBetween(modified, today).getHours();
        int minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(modified, today).getMinutes();
        int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(modified, today).getSeconds();

        if (years > 1) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.years), years);
        } else if (years > 0) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.year), years);
        } else if (months > 1) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.months), months);
        } else if (months > 0) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.month), months);
        } else if (days > 1) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.days), days);
        } else if (days > 0) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.day), days);
        } else if (hours > 1) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.hours), hours);
        } else if (hours > 0) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.hour), hours);
        } else if (minutes > 1) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.minutes), minutes);
        } else if (minutes > 0) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.minute), minutes);
        } else if (seconds > 1) {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.seconds), seconds);
        } else {
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(R.string.second), seconds);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void FragmentMethod() {
        RefreshList();
    }

    /**
     * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
     */
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }


    public void RefreshList(){
        //borra la galeria anterior
        if (myAdsObjectList!= null){
            myAdsObjectList.clear();
            AlertsList.clear();
        }
        //carga anuncios
        prepareAlerts();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        RefreshList();
    }




}
```

I uses the method :

```
@Override
    public void FragmentMethod() {
        RefreshList();
    }
```

**Alerts_Adapter:**

```
public class Alerts_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Alerts_Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String idPet;
    private String TipoAnuncio;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<MyAdsCard> anunciosList;
    private StorageReference mStorageReference;
    private String idUser;
    //llamar funcion de fragment

    AdapterCallback callback;

    public interface AdapterCallback{
        void FragmentMethod();
    }



    ArrayList<String> ChatIdList;
    ArrayList<String> OtherUserIdList;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, description, time;
        public ImageView thumbnail;
        public ImageButton btn_edit;
        public TextView et_typeAd;
        private TextView type_ad;
        private RelativeLayout type_adLayout;



        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
            btn_edit = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
            et_typeAd = view.findViewById(R.id.et_typeAd);
            type_ad = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.et_typeAd);
            type_adLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.type_adLayout);

        }

    }


    public Alerts_Adapter(Context mContext, List<MyAdsCard> anunciosList, AdapterCallback callback) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.anunciosList = anunciosList;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.myads_cardview, parent, false);

        ChatIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
        OtherUserIdList = new ArrayList<String>();


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //aquí carga los anuncios, los actualiza con bbdd, las imagenes
        final MyAdsCard anuncios = anunciosList.get(position);
        idPet=anuncios.getId();//coge id anuncio
        TipoAnuncio=anuncios.getTipoAnuncio();//coge tipo anuncio
        holder.title.setText(anuncios.getName());
        holder.description.setText(anuncios.getDescription());
        holder.time.setText(anuncios.getTime());
        if(anuncios.getTipoAnuncio().equals("Perdidos")) {
            holder.type_ad.setText("PERDIDO");
            holder.type_adLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.title_rounded_orange);
        }
        else if(anuncios.getTipoAnuncio().equals("Encontrados")){
            holder.type_ad.setText("ENCONTRADO");
            holder.type_adLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.title_rounded_green);
        }
        else if(anuncios.getTipoAnuncio().equals("Adopciones")){
            holder.type_ad.setText("ADOPCIÓN");
            holder.type_adLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.title_rounded_blue);

        }

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //FER INTENT QUE PASSI EL ID PER DESPRES A LA FITXA IMPRIMIR LANUNCI AMB AQUEST ID I TIPO ANUNCIO
                //para hacer intent en el onclick
                TipoAnuncio=anuncios.getTipoAnuncio();
                idPet=anuncios.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), DataPetActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("TipoAnuncioFicha", TipoAnuncio);
                intent.putExtra("IdAnuncioFicha", idPet);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        holder.btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.btn_edit);
                //agafa dades, i actualitza su pica.
                TipoAnuncio=anuncios.getTipoAnuncio();
                idPet=anuncios.getId();

            }
        });

        //picasso agafa url i ho converteix amb imatge
        Picasso.get()
                .load(anuncios.getImg())
                .resize(200, 200)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
    }




    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_alerts, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }


    /**
     * Click listener for popup menu items
     */
    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @SuppressLint("StringFormatMatches")
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                /*
                case R.id.action_editAd:
                    Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, EditDataPetActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("TipoAnuncio", TipoAnuncio);
                    intent.putExtra("IdAnuncio", idPet);
                    ((MisAnunciosActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                    return true;*/
                case R.id.action_deleteAd:
                    showAlert(R.string.alert_title,String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.alert_delete)), idPet);

                    //deleteAlerts();
                    return true;
                default:

            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void showAlert(int title, String message, final String idRoom){
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder =  new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this.mContext,R.style.MyDialogTheme)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.chat_alert_button_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        deleteAlerts();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.chat_alert_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    private void deleteAlerts() {
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref2 = rootRef.child("Usuarios").child(userId).child("Alerts").child(idPet);
        ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alerta borrada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        /*
//dir que refresqui llista myads SI FUNCIONA POSAR A MAPA I LLISTA QUAN ES CREA UN ANUNCI AMB ADDANUNCIO
        final AlertasFragment fragment = new AlertasFragment();
        fragment.RefreshList();
        //((AlertasFragment)mContext).RefreshList(); */
        //mCallBack.CallBackFragment();
        /*
        if(callback != null) {
            callback.FragmentMethod();
        }*/
        callback.FragmentMethod();
    }






    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return anunciosList.size();
    }
}
```

I uses this to call the function from fragment:

```
callback.FragmentMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write an interface callback for that.

There are plenty of examples on internet.

specific answer to your question

refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715025/how-to-return-a-callback-from-adapter-to-fragment-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass **this**, current class object to implement your `callback` upon or make an **anonymous class** implemetation or make an **object of AdapterCallback** and pass it like below:

Pass your fragment object and implement it.

```
adapter = new Alerts_Adapter(getActivity(), myAdsObjectList, this);
```

or make new anonymous object.

```
adapter = new Alerts_Adapter(getActivity(), myAdsObjectList, new AdapterCallback {
    @Override
    public void FragmentMethod(){
       // Here is your callback
    }
});
```

or make an object of `AdapterCallback` and pass like below.

```
adapter = new Alerts_Adapter(getActivity(), myAdsObjectList, adapterCallback);
```