# receiving callback from an adapter, but the calling class is not Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, callback, adapter

I've seen so many examples of receiving call back from adapter but the calling class were Activity or Fragment, but now I have an activity which calls ClassA you say and ClassA calls the adapter and I need the call back to be used in ClassA and not in the Activity,

I've seen so many examples of Activity or Fragment but not a class of other types:
[Callback from Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032933/callback-from-adapter)
or
[How to return a callback from Adapter to Fragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715025/how-to-return-a-callback-from-adapter-to-fragment-class/39715251)

Comment: And what's your question specifically? Did you expect an `Activity` or a `Fragment`? Or what did you expect? And could you please provide a _[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_?

Comment: Callback's are basic functionality which are triggered when a event occurs doesn't matter which class or type of class called triggered. 
Your question is not clear what you want to ask!

Comment: @Anmol I can accept your comment as accepted answer, I was looking for the difference while as you said, there is no difference, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Callback's are basic functionality which are triggered when an event occurs doesn't matter which class or type of class called triggered it.

Here's a really good tutorial on [Callback](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html)