# How do I call activity method from Adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have three Class

mainActivity.java

```
public class mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);

} 


public void firstDialog()
{

  //Do something
  //call next method

  secondDialog()

}

public void secondDialog()
{
  //Do something
}

}
```

Next is another class which is calling the adaptor class
secondclass.java

```
public class secondclass extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xyz);

        //calling and set adaptor
        adapter=new Myadaptopr(this,result);
        recyclerlist.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

//Now the Adaptor class

```
    public class Myadaptopr extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadaptopr.ViewHolder> {


     @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MedicineAdaptor.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       //In this function I need to call firstDialog() Method How Do I proceed.

    }

}
```

**My Question is:**

How do I call the methods of mainactivity.java class file. 
I have tried solution:
but didn't work because mainactivity class don't call and set the adapter. 
((mainactivity)context).firstDialog();

Comment: when will be the dialog shown??is there any button click??

Comment: try using callback http://stackoverflow.com/a/37535113/5381331

Comment: Why people are down vote the question. If there is any error with my question let me know. I will correct it. But please before down voting let me know I can more precisely write the question.

Comment: `mainactivity act = new mainactivity();` and call method as `act.firstDialog();`

Comment: This is just for representation. It can be call on Button click or normal call @kgandroid

Comment: create an interface in adapter and call the method of that interface in the activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Comment: create and use interface for accomplishing  ur purpose

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using interfaces:

First create an interface:

```
public interface myInterface{

  void myMethod();
}
```

Now you can extend the interface from the activity:

```
public class mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity implements myInterface
```

The method will now need the `override` annotation.

At this point you can simply call (from anywhere with context)

```
((myInterface) context).myMethod();
```

And you're done.

Hope this helps, for any question ask freely

## EDIT

I have to say something more.

**For the solution you are aiming:**

Pass the `first activity context` as a parameter of the `intent` to the `second activity`. then you create the `adaptor` with this `context` and not with the "`this`" of the `second activity`.

**What you should do**

Create an external class with a static method (a new file).

Create this method:

```
public class MyExternalClass{

  public static void myMethod(){
     //do stuff
  }
}
```

Now when you need this method call the following:

```
MyExternalCkass.myMethod();
```

And you are done.

Comment: where I need to define the interface... In mainactivity or in adaptor class

Comment: in a separate class file @AnkurKhandelwal

Comment: How will I pass context to adaptor class. As I am not calling it directly..  Or context=mainactivity.this will do

Comment: you are passing "Activity activity". use this @AnkurKhandelwal

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal ((myInterface) activity).myMethod();

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal check my edited answer. if you can't do it, please have a look at some tutorial first because it means you didn't studied enough before starting

Comment: Are you saying we have to create a separate interface for every single function???

Answer (score -1):

MainActivity is already stopped, so there is no point in calling a function from that class. If you want to call an Activity method from an Adapter, pass an Activity reference in the constructor while creating the Adapter. Make sure the method you want to call from the Adapter is declared 'public'. To call in Adapter, just use the Activity reference and call the method.

```
class MainActivity {
    onCreate() {
        CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public methodA() {
    }
}

class CustomAdapter {

    Activity mActivity;    

    CustomAdapter(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    // Call to function
    mActivity.methodA();
}
```

Comment: Not helped.. @Arjun

Comment: My point is, that MainActivity is not the active activity, so why would you want to call it in the first place. Add that functionality in the 'secondclass' and call it using the above answer code.