# How to run ProgressDialog with AsyncTask in ViewModel

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, viewmodel, android-context

I recently started to use `MVVM` pattern with `LiveData` and Room in my Android app.

In my `ViewModel` I fetch data from db using `AsyncTask`.
But sometimes I load from db some more heavy stuff(like list with few thousands items). Normally I would add a ProgressDialog to AsyncTask, start it in onPreExecute method and close it in onPostExecute. But ProgressDialog needs a `Context`:

```
new ProgressDialog(Context ctx)
```

I've read about separation between View ( `Activity` ) and `ViewModel` and that I should not use activities context in `ViewModel` classes. So how can I achieve that without having the activity context in my `ViewModel`?

Maybe I should use a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the show/hide progress dialog inside `Activity`.
Then `ViewModel` can notify to `Activity` to show dialog (using `listener`)

You can also check https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dev-todo-mvvm-live for more details
And [example using a listener to notify and pass data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37535113/5381331)