# Open a fragment from a recyclerview (which is a fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I have a fragment that contains a recycler view, in that recycler view I have a popup menu that I try to have one of its options launch another fragment, but I can not get it to work.
My adapter class:

```
  public class RecyclerAdapterMusico extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterMusico.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<Musico> listaM;

    public RecyclerAdapterMusico(Context context, ArrayList<Musico> listaMusicos) {
        mContext = context;
        listaM = listaMusicos;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View vista;
        vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_musicos, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(vista);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerAdapterMusico.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Musico musicoItem = (Musico) listaM.get(position);
        CircleImageView imagenMusico = holder.img;
        TextView nom = holder.nombre;
        TextView ins = holder.instrumento;
        TextView est = holder.estilo;
        TextView desc = holder.descripcion;
        TextView anun = holder.anuncios;
        ImageView busc = holder.buscando;
        ImageButton btnMenu = holder.menuButton;

        nom.setText(musicoItem.getNombre());
        ins.setText(musicoItem.getInstrumento().get(0));
        est.setText(musicoItem.getEstilo());
        desc.setText(musicoItem.getDescripcion());
        anun.setText(String.valueOf(musicoItem.getAnuncio().size()));

        btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //creacion del menu para el cardview
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.menuButton);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.navigation_visitar_perfil);
                //Listener del menu
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.itemVisitarPerfil:
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "VISITAR PERFIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;

                            case R.id.itemVisitarAnuncios:

                               /* FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();// If you're already inside another fragment
                                FragmentVisitarPerfil_Anuncios yfObj = new FragmentVisitarPerfil_Anuncios();
                                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedormivisitarperfil, yfObj).commit();*/

                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "VISITAR ANUNCIOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //mostrar menu
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });


        try {
            if (musicoItem.getBuscando().equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
                busc.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.yes));
            } else {
                busc.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.no));
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sale por aqui en caso de que venga del primer registro");
        }
        new BDBAA().accesoFotoPerfil("musico",'n',imagenMusico,mContext);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaM.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView img;
        ImageView buscando;
        TextView nombre, instrumento, estilo, descripcion, anuncios;
        ImageButton menuButton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //finds de los componentes de los items
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItemMusico);
            buscando = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBuscandoItemMusico);
            nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreMusicoItemMusico);
            instrumento = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtInstrumentoItemMusico);
            estilo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtEstiloItemMusico);
            descripcion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcionItemMusico);
            anuncios = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidadAnunciosItemMusico);
            menuButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMenuMusicos);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}



My Fragment class that contains the recycler:

public class FragmentMusicosTabInicio extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerViewMusicos;
    View vista;
    ArrayList<Musico> listaMusicos = new ArrayList<>();

    public FragmentMusicosTabInicio() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_musicos_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerViewMusicos = vista.findViewById(R.id.recyclerMusicos);
            new BDBAA().cargarDatos(listaMusicos, recyclerViewMusicos, getActivity(),"musico");
        return vista;
    }
```

and its layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabmusicos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    >

    <!--PARTE DE LOS ITEMS-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/md_black_1000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No olvides tu historia ni tu destino"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bob Marley"
                android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerMusicos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The menu contains two items

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_visitar_perfil"
        android:title="Ir al perfil"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_visitar_anuncios"
        android:title="Ir a anuncios"/>
</menu>
```

The intention is that clicking on "Anuncios" will open a fragment that belongs to a buttomNavigationView and that contains another recyclerview

This class is this:

```
  public class FragmentAnuncios extends Fragment {
    View vista;
    FloatingActionButton miFAB;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewAnuncios;
    Anuncio anuncio;
    ArrayList<Anuncio> lista;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anuncios_v_fragment_perfil, container, false);

        recyclerViewAnuncios = vista.findViewById(R.id.recycleranuncios);
        recyclerViewAnuncios.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        lista=new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Anuncio("NECESITAMOS BAJISTA ","Hola, somos un grupo que necesita incorporar a un bajista","25/05/2018","Asturias","Comillas","Pop/Rock","Bajista","Mujer"));
        lista.add(new Anuncio("NECESITAMOS BAJISTA ","Hola, somos un grupo que necesita incorporar a un bajista","25/05/2018","Asturias","Comillas","Pop/Rock","Bajista","Mujer"));
        lista.add(new Anuncio("NECESITAMOS BAJISTA ","Hola, somos un grupo que necesita incorporar a un bajista","25/05/2018","Asturias","Comillas","Pop/Rock","Bajista","Mujer"));
        lista.add(new Anuncio("NECESITAMOS BAJISTA ","Hola, somos un grupo que necesita incorporar a un bajista","25/05/2018","Asturias","Comillas","Pop/Rock","Bajista","Mujer"));
        lista.add(new Anuncio("NECESITAMOS BAJISTA ","Hola, somos un grupo que necesita incorporar a un bajista","25/05/2018","Asturias","Comillas","Pop/Rock","Bajista","Mujer"));

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager rcLayoutManager =layoutManager;
        recyclerViewAnuncios.setLayoutManager(rcLayoutManager);
        RecyclerAdapterAnuncioPropio adapterAnuncio=new RecyclerAdapterAnuncioPropio(getActivity(),lista);
        recyclerViewAnuncios.setAdapter(adapterAnuncio);


        miFAB = (FloatingActionButton) vista.findViewById(R.id.fabAñadirAnuncio);
        miFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                FragmentDialogAñadirAnuncio alerta = new FragmentDialogAñadirAnuncio();
                alerta.show(fm, "AlertaAnuncio");
            }
        });


        return vista;
    }
}
```

And the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/anuncios"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    >


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/recycleranuncios"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAñadirAnuncio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_teal_800"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I only find a solution to open the fragment if the "parent" activity extends from AppCompactActivity and not from a Fragment.

Any solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Note that you might want to make your adapter an inner class of the fragment, that will simplify things.  If you keep the adapter as a separate class, you'll need to add interface callbacks from the adapter to the fragment, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444375/how-to-create-interface-between-fragment-and-adapter

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it did not help me since it throws me an error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.pc.bandsnarts.Interfaces.AdapterCallBack.onMethodCallBack(android.view.MenuItem, android.content.Context)' on a null object reference . I do not know what to do :(