# SQLite database - update a row within a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a RecyclerView which displays a list of people, I have added an onClickListener to cycle through a traffic light colours.
All this works fine, but I am trying to set an update query within the onClickListener to change the data within the database against that row:

```
    String name = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME));
    String number = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NUMBER));
    Long id = pCursor.getLong(pCursor.getColumnIndex(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry._ID));
    holder.playerView.setTag(id);
    holder.itemView.setTag(id);
    holder.playerView.setText(name + "\n" + number);

    int answer = pCursor.getInt(pCursor.getColumnIndex(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_IS_PLAYING));

    if (answer == 0) {
        holder.redView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.greenView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.amberView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else if (answer == 1) {
        holder.greenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.amberView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.redView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else if (answer == 2) {
        holder.amberView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.redView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.greenView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    holder.allTheViews[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {                                                         
            ManualPlayingChange.notToPlaying(holder);
        }
    });

    holder.allTheViews[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {                 
            ManualPlayingChange.notToPlaying(holder);
        }
    });

    holder.allTheViews[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {                 
            ManualPlayingChange.notToPlaying(holder);
        }
    });
```

I am thinking I need to pass the database into the adapter class? and then run an update query, but is there a way just perform an update on the database without having the pass it through?

Comment: yes you can use interface

Comment: register an interface to your activity and pass that interface to adapter now invoke the specified method of interface on click and you will get the callback in your activity where you have regsitered/implemented/anoymously initialsed your interface .. now in activity you can call your db updated query

Comment: @AdeelTurk thanks for the info, one question, how do you pass through the interface into the adapter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444375/how-to-create-interface-between-fragment-and-adapter

Comment: if my comment helped ya please upvote it .

Comment: @AdeelTurk it did and i have :)

Comment: thanx have a happy coding