# How do I interact with the AlertDialog View that is inside a Fragment from an Adapter inside an Adapter inside the AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

The title almost says everything. I need suggestions on how can I do this. I might just add the outer adapter as a `View` on the `AlertDialog` to make it a little less complicated but I still don't know how can I interact with the `AlertDialog` from the inner adapter. I'm using `RecyclerView`.

This is how my data looks like.

```
"list_outer": [
  {
    "list_inner": [

    ]
  }
]
```

For example, if I select something from list_inner, I want to update the UI of the `AlertDialog`.

@Sreedev P R suggested that I use an `interface` that is to be passed on the adapters `constructor`. The problem is that there's another step before the `AlertDialog` can reach the inner adapter, currently, because I haven't added the outer adapter as a `View` yet. And if I do make the outer adapter just a `View`, I still can't think of a clean way to pass that value to the `AlertDialog`. Is it fine to reshow an `AlertDialog`? Would it not create a memory leak? I might just do that if that's fine.

This is how my app is structured.

```
Fragment
    |
    AlertDialog
        |
        Adapter outer
            |
            Adapter inner
```

Adapter inner needs to be able to communicate or change the UI of AlertDialog

This the layout for the `AlertDialog`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/lytDlgAddItemToTicketMain"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include3"
        layout="@layout/dialog_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/DialogScrollViewHeight"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include3">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/lstAddItemToTicketAddOns"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:listitem="@layout/adptr_modifier">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is it's code.

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

lst.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));

AdapterOuter adptr = new ModifierAdapter(ctx, arrayList);
lst.setAdapter(adptr);
```

UPDATE

To make it a little complicated, I ditch the `AlertDialog` thing and made it a `Fragment`.

Comment: Use an interface to provide callback

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Which `class` should `implement` the `interface`? Is it the `Fragment` or the one that contains the `AlertDialog`?

Comment: Now that I think about it more, it would be the inner adapter that needs to `implement` the `interface` right? How do I use it on the adapter?

Comment: You might have to pass it in  the adapter's constructor.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444411/10464730 And which adapter?

Comment: Yes, like this. The adapter will be where you need to write function for alert dialog button action.

Comment: So, I do really need to make the outer adapter a `View` it seems.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I should do this? Like how do I setup my `Fragment`. Because that answer did show a snippet of the relevant parts of the `Fragment`.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain further about your problem ?. You have a fragment which contains a recycler view and within that another recycler view ?, and what exactly do you want the callback to do ?

Comment: Also there is an other solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444411/10464730, that is to use an EventBus. I found it much easier than interfaces as interfaces might produce null pointer exceptions if not handled properly.

Comment: It's already all in the title. That's basically what I want to do. That link only got answer for `Adapter` to `Fragment` communication. The adapter is inside another adapter that is inside an `AlertDialog`. You get it?

Comment: You can pass the interface as param to the outer adapter, and the same should be passed to the inner adapter. So whatever you interact with in the inner adapter will reach the Alert dialog

Comment: Oh. That might work. But how will the `AlertDialog` listen to that from the `Fragment`?

Comment: Can you show me how you implemented the recyclerviews within alert dialog ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196303/discussion-between-sreedev-p-r-and-rminaj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting the `AlertDialog` into a `Fragment` and applying @Sreedev P R's suggestion of using an `interface`, I was able to make it work.