# Android AlertDialog How to display information from RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to implement an `AlertDialog` in Android. When you click on an item in a `RecyclerView` it shows some information about the element. How can I hand over necessary informations? Or can I at least hand over an object that has the information?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Set a tag on the view that is to be clicked and later retrieve the object from the tag along with the information it holds.

Comment: @Piyush Can you post an example pls?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560276/custom-alert-dialog-with-recyclerview