# RecyclerView inside a Dialog is overlapping other content of dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a `Dialog` that looks like this

[image: RecyclerView inside Dialog]

Here, the elements in orange rectangles are fixed header and footer sections of the `Dialog`. The elements inside blue rectangle are placed dynamically depending on what content is to be shown.
Here it the XML for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <!-- some views -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/body_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_section"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer_section"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <!-- some views -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

It works fine when I place other views inside the blue area, but when a `RecyclerView` is placed inside it and items are dynamically added to it, it grows in size and overlaps the text in header section and pushes the footer section to bottom. How can I make the `RecyclerView` cover only the blue area?

Comment: Why do u need a linear layout in the ConstraintLayout ? It can be achieved with a single constraint Layout !

Comment: I hope it'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/33560276

Comment: @SantanuSur I've placed the different sections inside `LinearLayout` just to make code look clean and keep all their content constrained without having to apply constraints to every single `View` in header and footer section.

Comment: @ViralPatel thank you, but the link you shared does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Use height 0dp in body section so it will fit between header and footer**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <!-- some views -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/body_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_section"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer_section"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <!-- some views -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it makes the body section disappear.

Comment: what widget are you placing inside body section?

Comment: I'm placing a `RecyclerView` and 2 `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Adding `layout_constrainedHeight="true"` does solve the problem of `RecyclerView` overlapping the content in header. But it still pushes the footer section out of view when elements are added to it.

Comment: give height and width of recyclerview 0 dp and top,bottom,start,end constraint to parent ,give top to bottom of textview if your recyclerview is below textview

Comment: dont use recyclerview height as wrap content

Comment: Well, I had to use `layout_constrainedHeight="true"` on the `RecyclerView` and a fixed height on the root layout to solve the problem. It still seems a woorkaround though as the fixed height is not appropriate for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I use ScrollView to tackle this,

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_max="250dp"
                app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                >

                 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
                   />

            </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The main attributes are these 3

```
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="250dp"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```