# call public class and refresh list view in the activity

Tags: java, android

i have a MainActivity with a list view.
in this activity is a `private void showList()` which query all of my database and show it in the list view.

i have another public class "Sync" which send an http post to my MYSQL Database, get the result and write this into the android database.

i would like to realize, that on each resume of the main activity, the public class Sync will call and on finish the list view in the main activity should be refresh.

in the MainActivity, i call it like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   new Sync.SyncMYSQL(context).execute();
}
```

this is the Sync Class:

```
public class Sync {


        // MYSQL => Database
        static class SyncMYSQL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            Context context;

            public SyncMYSQL(Context c) {
                this.context = c;
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {

                       // DO SOMETHING


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Log.e("-->", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("-->", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
                return null;
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                // DO SOMETHING

            }
        }
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class OverviewData extends Fragment {

    private View FragementView;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ListView ListView;
    DatabaseListAdapter databaseListAdapter;
    Context context;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = getContext();

        FragementView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview, container, false);
        ListView = (ListView) FragementView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        showList();

        return FragementView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new Sync.SyncMYSQL(context, 0).execute();
    }




    private void showList() {

        ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> databaseList = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseList.clear();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE;

        Cursor c1 = dbHandler.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DatabaseListItems databaseListItems = new DatabaseListItems();

                    databaseListItems.setIdentifier(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID)));

                    databaseList.add(databaseListItems);

                } while (c1.moveToNext()) ;
            }
            c1.close();

        }


        databaseListAdapter = new DatabaseListAdapter(getActivity(), databaseList);
        ListView.setAdapter(databaseListAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: the problem is, that i dont know, how i can refresh the list view of the main activity AFTER the Sync process ist executed

Comment: there is nothing in `doInBackground()` how are you taking the data from server?

Comment: this part i comment out, because that is not important, fact is: i get data of my MYSQL Database and this data will write in the android database. but now i have to find a way to refresh the list view, to show the new data

Comment: ok, when you saved the data in the `SQLite` pass the data to adapter too and call `notifiyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Before just use dataList notifyDataSetChanged in the last line

Answer (score 0):

For the listView adapter -

firstly set the data like

```
adapter=new Adapter(context,newDataList);
```

adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: mmmh, maybe i have to say that i use a custom list view adapter. i will post the showList Function in my first post now

Comment: I am talking about custom list view adapter only! make a constructor in adapter class to receive dataList.

Comment: sry, but i dont know what i have to do, where should i put your code? int the post onPostExecute of the Sync class?

Answer (score 0):

its bad idea to refresh list data every time in `onResume`(because, its load data whenever you open and close activity, or come back from last activity) instead of that call sync method in `onStart/onCreate`(at end of `onCreate`).

---

To refresh listview use interface. implement interface in activity and add below code in interface method after that call interface method from onPostExecute

```
if(databaseListAdapter != null)
databaseListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: if i only put this code to my `onPostExecute`, i get the error: `cannot find symbol variable databaseListAdapter`

Comment: check edited answer and here is answer how to use interface http://stackoverflow.com/a/12142530/1168654

Comment: what do you mean with implement interface?

Comment: sry sry sry, but can you tell me where i have to put the code into my code parts? i try to implement the interface - but i think that this is not correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use a cursor loader. As soon as you database changes the cursor loader will call **onLoadFinished()** in which you can update your list view.

Initialize a loader:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
```

In your onResume() restart it:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);
```

In onDetach()/onDestroy() destroy it:

```
getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(1);
```

Make your class implement: **LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks**
And you will have to override its three main methods. **onLoadFinished()** will help you yo update the UI/list view.