# How to Get a callback for activity started from inside arrayadapter for listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, callback, onactivityresult

How to start an activity from inside ArrayAdapter and get a call back when the activity is finished(just like onActivityResult)?

Following code is on post execute of an asynctask that is started on the button click of a button displayed in each listview row.

```
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.DUMMY_CONSTANT);
```

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142255/call-activity-method-from-adapter

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, try using this instead:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ... });
```

Edit. You can also create interface, implement it in your acitvity and pass it to your adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
My Pscudoe code:-- Create call back method using interface 
and make call back wherever you want
MyListener listener;

  public interface MyListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onClick(View view, int position);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    listener.onCardClick(view, getPosition());
}
```

From Listview onitem:---