# How to let OnClick in viewholder recyclerview adapter Adapter call Activity's function

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

How to let OnClick in view holder recyclerview adapter call Activity's function

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            final Jour jour = listItems.get(position);
            holder.datenumber1.setText(jour.getDate());
            holder.datetext1.setText(jour.getJour());
            holder.object.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,jour.getDate().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            ((Acceuil) context).loadrecyclerviewdata2(jour.getDate().toString());
                    }
            });


    }
```

**LOGS**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         Process: com.example.karim.tkwira, PID: 29380
>                         java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to
>   com.example.karim.tkwira.Acceuil
>                             at com.example.karim.tkwira.Jour_adapter$1.onClick(Jour_adapter.java:51)
>                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
>                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29380 SIG: 9
>       Application terminated.

```js
package com.example.karim.tkwira;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
public class Acceuil extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String SESSION="session";
    private String email ;
    private List<Jour> listItems;
    private List<Heure> listItems2;
    RecyclerView joursliste;
    RecyclerView heuresliste;
    private static final String URL_DAY="http://192.168.1.3/takwira/gettime.php";
    private static final String URL_DAY2="http://192.168.1.3/takwira/afficher.php";
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acceuil);
        SharedPreferences profil =getSharedPreferences(SESSION,0);
        joursliste=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.jourslist);
        heuresliste=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.heurslist);
        email= profil.getString("email","");
        listItems= new ArrayList<>();
        listItems2= new ArrayList<>();
        loadrecyclerviewdata();
        loadrecyclerviewdata2("02-06-2300");
    }
    public void loadrecyclerviewdata2(final String ch1){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("get data ...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_DAY2,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Heures");
                            for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                                JSONObject o =array.getJSONObject(i);
                                Heure heure = new Heure(o.getString("heure"));
                                listItems2.add(heure);
                            }
                            adapter2 = new Heure_adapter(listItems2,getApplicationContext());
                            heuresliste.setAdapter(adapter2);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"errrrrreur",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("day",ch1);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void loadrecyclerviewdata(){
       final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
       progressDialog.setMessage("wait...");
       progressDialog.show();
       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DAY,
               new Response.Listener<String>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                       try {
                           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                           JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("days");
                           for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                              JSONObject o =array.getJSONObject(i);
                               Jour jour = new Jour(
                                       o.getString("journombre"),o.getString("jourtext"));
                               listItems.add(jour);
                           }
                           adapter = new Jour_adapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                           joursliste.setAdapter(adapter);

                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               },
               new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"errrrrreur",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
}
```

Comment: Pass `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` to pass Activity Context in Adapter

Comment: Post your activity please.

Comment: i want to run loadrecyclerviewdata2() function from the adapter

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12142255/5611425)

Comment: @KarimTebib((Acceuil) context).loadrecyclerviewdata2(jour.getDate().toString());
in this line context is  not your activity (Acceuil) context that's why it throw classCastException you need to pass Activity context when you initialize the Adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
//In RecyclerViewAdapter
public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

//after assigning ids

object.setOnClickListener(this);


//In your Activity
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

    ((YourRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new YourRecyclerViewAdapter
            .MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            if (id == R.id.YOUR_OBJECT_ID) {
                Jour jour = listItems.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"position ="+jour.getDate(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i want to run loadrecyclerviewdata2() function from the adapter

Comment: in if condition call loadrecyclerviewdata2(jour.getDate().toString());