# Call activity method from recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, interface, android-recyclerview

I was trying to call an activity method from my recycler view adapter.
What I did,
I have **created an interface, implemente on the required activity override its method** and trying to call from adapter
I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to my.package.Interface.InterfaceName
Below is code

MethodCaller.java

```
public interface MethodCaller {
    void deleteAddress(String did);
}
```

AddressAdapter.java

```
public class AddressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Address> list;       

    public AddressAdapter(Context context, List<Address> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AddressAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.address_single, parent, false);
        return new AddressAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddressAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Address address = list.get(position);

        holder.btn_deleteAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Address address = list.get(position);
                final String id = address.getId();

                //if(context instanceof MethodCaller){
                    ((MethodCaller)context).deleteAddress(id);  //ClassCastException - Error
                //}
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {           
        public Button btn_deleteAddress;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            btn_deleteAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_deleteAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

AddressActivity.java

```
public class AddressActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MethodCaller {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_address);

        //CODE
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAddress(String did) {
        Toast.makeText(this, did, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                deleteAddressRequest(id);
                                break;
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();*/
    }
}
```

Comment: probably copy of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142255/call-activity-method-from-adapter

Comment: Brother https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142255/call-activity-method-from-adapter is not working for me thats why I have to create this new post, please read the question properly I have tried everything that is written here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142255/call-activity-method-from-adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This one**

```
public MethodCaller methodCaller;
public AddressAdapter(Context context, List<Address> list,MethodCaller methodCaller) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.methodCaller = methodCallerl;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddressAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Address address = list.get(position);

    holder.btn_deleteAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Address address = list.get(position);
            final String id = address.getId();
            methodCaller .deleteAddress(id);
         }
    });
}
```

**AddressActivity.java**

pass interface in your adapter like this;

`new AddressAdapter(context,list,this);`

Comment: Thanks @Hardik Vasani it is working perfectly fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can call the activity method from adapter using activity context you pass in your adapter

```
((YourActivityName)mContext).customMethod();
```

If you are using the same adapter for multiple class then you can add a check before performing the operation.

```
if(mContext instanceof YourActivityName){
       ((YourActivityName)mContext).yourActivityMethod();
   }
```

for more detail follow this https://trinitytuts.com/tips/call-activity-method-inside-adapter/