# how to get Custom listview adapter value and set value in two edittext one by one

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

**CustomListAdapter.class**

How do I get the value of `TextView eng` from listview and set this value in two different edittext one by one.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> implements View.OnClickListener{

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;

    public CustomListAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.route, dataModels);
        this.dataSet = dataModels;
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView eng;
        TextView hindi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object = getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) object;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.eng:
                String s = dataModel.getStationEng();
                //mStart.(FareCalculatorActivity.class).getClasses().setText(s.trim().toUpperCase().toString());
                break;

            case R.id.hindi:
                String s1 = dataModel.getStationEng();
                break;
        }
    }
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route, parent, false);
            viewHolder.eng = convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng);
            viewHolder.hindi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hindi);
            result = convertView;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
        viewHolder.eng.setText(dataModel.getStationEng());
        viewHolder.hindi.setText(dataModel.getStationhindi());
        viewHolder.eng.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.eng.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.hindi.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.hindi.setTag(position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

[image]

get value from custom listview adapter and set value to edittext one by one.
this listview is filter listview, I want the value of listview and set to the edittext

Comment: Look at the answer I added, should do the required job.

Answer (score 1):

Either you create a separate callback interface or use the `View.OnClickListener`. Hereby modified your existing adapter class.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    View.OnClickListener listener;

    public CustomListAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels, Context context, View.OnClickListener listener) {
        super(context, R.layout.route, dataModels);
        this.dataSet = dataModels;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView eng;
        TextView hindi;
    }


    private int lastPosition = -1;
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route, parent, false);
            viewHolder.eng = convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng);
            viewHolder.hindi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hindi);
            result = convertView;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
        viewHolder.eng.setText(dataModel.getStationEng());
        viewHolder.hindi.setText(dataModel.getStationhindi());
        viewHolder.eng.setOnClickListener(listener);
        viewHolder.eng.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.hindi.setOnClickListener(listener);
        viewHolder.hindi.setTag(position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

now change the call where you have initialized adapter in activity/fragment like below

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(data,context,new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object = getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) object;
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.eng:
                String s = dataModel.getStationEng();
                //mStart.(FareCalculatorActivity.class).getClasses().setText(s.trim().toUpperCase().toString());
                // set to editText
                break;

            case R.id.hindi:
                String s1 = dataModel.getStationEng();
                // set to editText
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: case R.id.hindi:
                String s1 = dataModel.getStationEng();
                // set to editText
              //it show me error when i call edittext here
                break;

Comment: have you declared any edittext instance where you calling this adapter ? I am expecting you should have two edittext in your activity or fragment where setting up adapter.

Comment: @pankajsharma Is something wrong ? yesterday you have accepted the answer but today seems you have withdrawn it. May I know the reason please.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue you facing now ?

Comment: sorry for devoting i got solution if (mStart.isFocused())
                {
                    String s = mList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    mStart.setText(s);
                }

Comment: @pankajsharma **There are many ways to solve the issue. I spent more than hour to fix your issue and even you agreed on the solution and accepted the answer as it worked for you. but atleast we shouldn't withdrawn our answer if we found some other way to solve our problem.** Anyway never mind. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the ways that solve the problem are :-

1.Using the interface to pass data from adapter class to the activity .

2. Calling an function defined in the activity with the data got on the click listener , and using it to set the edit-texts.

[This link will help   to find the above mentioned approaches in  more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142255/call-activity-method-from-adapter)

Hope this helps.