# Problem with a Button inside a Custom Dialog (created in RecyclerView Adapter)

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a `RecyclerView` , in each item there's a (Share) button that prompts a custom dialog which contains a `TextView` and a `Button`.
so, I build the custom dialog inside the `Adapter` of `RecyclerView` , everything is fine except for the button's appearance.

it looks like there's a white overlay on top of it and when I click on it, the overlay slightly disappears.

This is what the Button looks like in xml:
[image]

and here's what I get: 
[image]

here's my custom dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_copy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/copy_address"
        android:theme="@style/button"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the java code creating the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dialog, null));
    builder.setTitle(view.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.share));
share = builder.create();
share.show();
```

**Note**: I think the problem is related to the Inflater, particularly this line:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

because in MainActivity it works fine when I replace it by this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
```

but I can't use it since I can't get Activity from inside the adapter.

I hope my question is clear, I'd appreciate your help.

**Edit:** code of `@style/button`

```
<style name="button" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorGray</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Is the `theme` and `style` tag is required on your button?

Comment: @Tepits yes, `theme` is for the green background and white text,  I tried removing both but still the same problem. I removed the `style` tag now, I found that it's unnecessary.

Comment: Since it is from `style` tag, its better to use `style` tag than `theme` tag. Like `style="@style/button"`. Check if this solve your issue.

Comment: @Tepits I tried it but still the same problem.

Comment: Okay. Can you share your code on your `button` style? `@style/button`

Comment: @Tepits sure, I added it in the question. Although, I don't believe it's related to the style because I used the dialog in MainActivity and everything worked fine, the problem is when I build the dialog inside the adapter.

Comment: I see. Then try to pass your `activity` or `context` inside your adapter so that you can do the `LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();` which is you have said that is working.

Comment: Check this link on getting activity from adapter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142255/call-activity-method-from-adapter

Comment: @Tepits Thanks ! I tried it first but it didn't change, but it worked when I changed the android:layout_width and android:layout_height to "wrap_content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tepits comment , and some changes .. i found a solution .

first, as this suggested [Call Activity method from adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142255/call-activity-method-from-adapter)

I changed `LayoutInflater inflater` to this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=  ((MainActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
```

and then changed `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` in the parent layout in dialog.xml to `wrap_content` and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

change your parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" to 
ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar

Comment: Thanks Hossam but I found the solution.