# Callback from an adapter to a function inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

My adapter callback is not working.

I want to activate an alert dialog to pop up after the user clicks on one of the cards in recycle view. To implement the same I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27716788/10792358) answer. During runtime, when I click on any of the cards, my application crashes and refreshes back to the home page of my application.

This is the error output of the LogCat.
First half of Logcat.
[image: logcat1]

Second half of Logcat:

[image: logcat2]

My fragment file. This fragment is part of one of three fragments inside the tabbed activity.

**SpecializationFrag.java**

```
public class SpecializationFrag extends Fragment implements AdapterCallback{

    // This is minimum reproducible code. 
    // other code which I found unnecessary are skipped
    
    @Override
    public void onMethodCallback( ) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Inside fragment, methodcallback ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

My adapter file.
**SpecializationAdapter.java**

```
public class SpecializationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SpecializationAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<DoctorsList> doctorsListArrayList;
    private AdapterCallback adapterCallback;
    
    // some more code that I've skipped
    
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public SpecializationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DoctorsList> doctorsListArrayList){ // constructor for initialization
            this.context = context;
            this.doctorsListArrayList = doctorsListArrayList;
            try{
                adapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
            }catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.d("Error", e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull com.example.appointmentmodule.Specialization.SpecializationAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            
            holder.Specialization.setText(doctorsList.getSpecialization());

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try{
                        adapterCallback.onMethodCallback();

                    }catch (ClassCastException e){
                        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            
        }
    }

    }
```

adapterCallback file.

**AdapterCallback.java**

```
public interface AdapterCallback {

void onMethodCallback();
}
```

Comment: Error you are getting is for Zipexception. Are you trying to read any zip file?

Comment: No. But still I am getting this strange zip error.